# How to get information about a chrome extension from the extension url?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension installed which has a built-in browser(which presumably just loads a page in an iframe). Using this built-in browser I navigate to my locally hosted react app at *localhost:3000*, console logging `window.location` gives an indication that the page is nested within a chrome extension as `window.location.ancestorOrigins` has a length of 1 with a value of `chrome-extension://gjagmgiddbbciopjhllkdnddhcglnemk` at index 0; how can I get information about this chrome extension such as its name from this URL or any other way of doing so if this way is not possible?

Comment: Not possible unless the extension intentionally exposes something in DOM or via web_accessible_resources in its manifest.json.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want more info about an extension with an ID saved into this URL in your question.

So there is a simple way to do it using extension API.

1. You could use `get` method from [management API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/management/#method-get). It has `id` param in the query so that you will receive a single element as a response.
2. If you want to pull data about all extensions that are installed you could simply use `getAll` method from the same API I showed before.

If you receive this ID in content-script. Then use `runtime` API to send this ID to the MV3 service worker and parse it as described above.

MV3 API provides promises. I showed an example for Chrome API, but it wold work for other common browsers. Also, you could find this method on the extension API polyfill.

Hope this would help.